# Filtering on multiple columns using iloc or loc

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe I built by scraping multiple excel files. one of the problems is that the header from the excel file (the column names) gets repeated for every file that gets concatenated into the dataframe.

I would like to drop the rows where the value is equal to the column names.

The line below gets me the correct boolean mask but I just can't seem to find a clean way to filter the data frame with the below condition

```
(df.iloc[:,0:13] == df.columns[0:13])
```

I've solved the issue with the below lines but I was hoping there was a cleaner or more pythonic way to write it because it feels like I'm missing something.

```
df1 = df[(df[(df.iloc[:,:13] == df.columns[:13])]).notna()].iloc[:,:13].copy()
df = df.drop(df1[df1['Name'].notnull()].index)
```

See the below sample table:

```
sample = pd.DataFrame(data = [['name', 'description', 'qty', 'units', 'wall height', 'xyz'],
                     [17,  8, 34,  5, 41,'xyz'],
                     [23, 16, 25, 43, 48,'abc'],
                     [15, 44, 21,  9,  3,'cde'],
                     [14, 16, 40, 26,  6, 'efg'],
                     ['name', 'description', 'qty', 'units', 'wall height','efg'],
                    ], 
             columns=['name', 'description', 'qty', 'units', 'wall height','address'])
```

With the above sample I would be trying to filter out index locations 0 and 5 where columns 0:5 are equal to column name 0:5. Note that column 5('address') with never match any values in the field.

Hopefully someone has a more pythonic way to solve me above problem.

TIA

Comment: "one of the problems is that the header from the excel file (the column names) gets repeated for every file that gets concatenated into the dataframe" - this sounds like an XY problem. Why not fix the problem at the source?

Comment: I'm using openpyxl to write several hundred excel files into a single dataframe by copying a sheet from the excel file into a dateframe. The sheet that is being copied over contains a data dump that's used in the individual excel files. That sheet could contain anywhere from 100 to 100,000 rows. most of the time the header is row 0 but not all the time. I'm not certain if there is an efficient way to filter out rows in my openpyxl function. it would have to be very efficient given the number of files that get opened and copied. That may be a little out of my wheel house but open to suggestions

Comment: I guess the deciding factor is "most of the time the header is row 0 but not all the time." Without more detail on the "not all the time," it's hard to suggest further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can filter the dataframe using boolean indexing:

```py
mask = (sample.iloc[:, 0:5] == sample.columns[0:5]).all(axis=1)
print(sample[~mask])
```

Prints:

```
  name description qty units wall height address
1   17           8  34     5          41     xyz
2   23          16  25    43          48     abc
3   15          44  21     9           3     cde
4   14          16  40    26           6     efg
```

Comment: That's perfect thanks, super readable. I just changed one lined it per below:
sample.loc[~(sample.iloc[:, 0:5] == df.columns[0:5]).all(axis=1)]

Answer (score 1):

Try with `ne` (not equals or `!=`) and `any`:

```
>>> df[df.iloc[:, 0:5].ne(df.columns[0:5]).any(axis=1)]

  name description qty units wall height address
1   17           8  34     5          41     xyz
2   23          16  25    43          48     abc
3   15          44  21     9           3     cde
4   14          16  40    26           6     efg
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.query`. Below I wrote an example using only two columns, just add the rest of them in the query.

```
df = df.query("name != 'name' and description != 'description'")
```

This only works if all the lines you want to remove are the same, ie, ['name', 'description', 'qty', 'units', 'wall height','efg']. If that's not true, you might solve it by using separate queries:

```
df = df.\
query("name != 'name'").\
query(description != 'description')
```

Comment: Appreciate the comment but i was trying to avoid having to explicitly list columns by using slices andrej and corralien above have my ideal solve for this problem